# Rspec stub expectation for an instance of a class

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want something like the following:

`foo.should_receive(:bar).with(an_instance_of(Bla)).....`

Is this possible?

**Edit:** According to the [rspec message expectations](http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/message_expectations.html) page it is possible exactly as I have written above.

Comment: You should then answer your own question for completeness or is something still amiss?

Comment: Alright then, have answered my question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you can do exactly what I had hoped:

`foo.should_receive(:bar).with(an_instance_of(Bla))`